# Importing css styles from a 3rd party library in React

Tags: css

Dumb question. How do you import styles from a 3rd party library? The css file for this library is located in the node modules folder in my app.

I try to require it into my components css file like so...

`@import url(~react-input-range/lib/css/index.css);`

But I don't think that is working. Also, after importing successfully do I edit the 3rd party css file to make changes or do I need to import the class names into my components css file and edit them there?

Comment: Why do you need to import CSS separately, directly importing the `InputRange` from `react-input-range` component and using it should give you the desired CSS ? Also this library has specified clearly on how to override classes.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use

```
import 'react-input-range/lib/css/index.css';
```

to import the default styling. Remember to have css loader in your webpack config.